# Battery died when updating from 12.04 to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, battery, dist-upgrade

I started the update and went to sleep but I forgot to plugin AC adapter.

When i woke up, laptop was off.  I plugged in the AC cord and turned it on.

Ubuntu boots and it is on 12.10 but may items are missing and neither gnome nor unity seem to work properly. It's also very slow and freezes sometimes. Is there a way to correct all those issues ? or revert back to 12.04 then re update to 12.10 without losing my data ?

Answer (score 0):

To go back to 12.04 You would have to back up your data and reinstall.

You may try the following to fix 12.10:

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and run `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

This *might* fix your system.

Answer (score 0):

i had something similar happen to me.... i was able to pull up a separate console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, logged in then obtained root using `su -`. Then i ran the following command

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

which took a long time to run but it fixed my desktop and icons.

Comment: The problem i am now faced with is my wireless network is not working

Answer (score 0):

Try running

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`